# Give me an R and I'll run!

Tags: riddle, word, letters

Give me an R and I'll run

Give me an AR and I'll come running

Give me a T and I'll stop you from moving

Give me a D and I'll make you move

Leave me alone and I'll send you in different directions!

Can you tell my name?

---

*As far as I know, this is original.*

Comment: Give me an S and an T and I'll try so hard to move that I'll I need the G and the E when I get the EL and the E this moment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your name is:

> **[RIVE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rive)**, as in 'split or tear apart violently'.

If we 'give' you the letters mentioned...

> Adding **R** produces a **RIVER**, which *runs* from its source to the sea.
>
>  Adding **AR** produces **ARRIVE**, suggesting *coming* to a specific location.
>
>  Adding **T** produces a **[RIVET](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rivet)** - a metal bolt for fastening materials together (i.e. *stopping them from moving*).
>
>  Adding **D** produces **DRIVE**, suggesting *moving* (as in a car, for instance).
>
>  Meanwhile, leaving the word as it is, the definition of **RIVE** is as mentioned in the first line of this answer: 'to tear apart' - as if something has been pulled *in different directions*!